# What are the most important metrics when monitoring openDJ?

Tags: opends, opendj

and how do you decide on what monitoring method to use (LDAP monitoring, SNMP, JMX or the logs). Is it worth it to implement all of them? How different are they?
I pulled the metrics through all of these methods and they seem to be very similar to me. I'm new to working with directory servers so I'm interested in what others would think.

Also, after you pull the metrics, how do you make use of them (view them with jconsole for example?)

Answer (score 0):

With OpenDJ, all metrics are equally available through LDAP and JMX. SNMP only has a subset of the metrics, i.e. the ones that are defined in the standard directory MIB.

When monitoring any server, I don't think a single capture of metrics is useful. What you want to compute average and running average over sample periods, define thresholds for some of the metrics and raise alert when those thresholds are met.